# Could you recommend some elegant way of creating reusable components with JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, components

I would like to have a set of nice tools in JavaScript for creating a small, reusable components easily. Component builder should have some nice API to create an html output for given data, which can be embedded directly on website. An example would be:

```
var data = smth; // some data, probably JSON ...
var builder = new Builder();
$(container).html( builder.build('user_details_template').with(data) );
```

This could render, for instance:

```
<div>
   <h1>User details</h1>
   <span class="username">Aaron Rodgers</span>
   <span class="description">Best QB in the entire world</span>
</div>
```

Pardon subjective example.

Now, is there some neat way in JavaScript to build such tool? In Java I would build or use some template engine which could accept arbitrary data and render HTML output.

I'm not a JavaScript expert, so the only tools I can think of are string concatenation and regular expressions.

But what are the best practices to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: After some hints, I have found: http://mustache.github.com/. Any thoughts on that library over jQuery templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template system in jquery ui is in planning phase: http://api.jquery.com/template/.   However there exist alternative libraries like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: I can see that this plugin is hosted on jquery account on github. Does it mean that it will end up in official jquery release, or maybe already have?

Comment: well, actually it's not a part of jQUery anymore. Documentation states, that it has been moved to jQuery UI project. It's now in 'planning' phase, making my life much harder ;) See this reference: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template

Comment: if you could update your response with the alternative library like Mustache (see my comment) and a word that Template will be developed under jQuery UI, then I will gladly accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples of the google closure template library.  Usage is expressed in a very similar way to your example.

https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js